# what does " |= "and " ^= " mean in java?

Tags: java

this is a function for changing bit value of image. what does `|=` and  `^=` mean?

```
private int setBitValue(int n,int location,int bit)  {
    int toggle=(int)Math.pow(2,location),bv=getBitValue(n,location);
    if(bv==bit)
       return n;
    if(bv==0 && bit==1)
       n|=toggle;        // what does it do?
    else if(bv==1 && bit==0)
       n^=toggle;        // what does it do?

    return n;
}
```

Comment: the question is regardless to swing;

Answer (score 4):

Its the same short form as in +=

```
n |= toogle
```

is the same as

```
n = n | toogle
```

the | is here the binary-or operator
and ^ is the binary xor-operator

Answer (score 2):

They are short hand assignment operations.

```
n|=toggle;       is equivalent to           n=n|toggle;
```

and

```
n^=toggle;       is equivalent to           n=n^toggle;
```

And

```
| is bitwise OR    
^ is bitwise XOR
```

Answer (score 1):

They're the bitwise OR equals and the bitwise XOR equals operators. They are mainly used for dealing with bit flags. I highly recommend [this article](http://www.wildbunny.co.uk/blog/2012/11/07/understanding-binary/) if you want to learn more about bitwise and bit-shifting operations.

Answer (score 0):

These are shorthand bitwise operators. Like `+=` using `|=` is the same as:

```
a = a | b;
```

Read the Oracle Documentation about [Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) for further information.